# Does the death of a party involved in the execution of a will mean that they do not inherit?

Tags: united-states, pennsylvania, inheritance, probate

A friend of mine is engaged in a lengthy probate process over her inheritance from her parents with her brother as the executor. Without getting into details of why it's been so protracted, it's been going on for well over a year now with all of the attendant drama and legal measures. Her health has been poor, and recently she's been worried that she might die (with attendant nightmares of parties involved plotting to hasten the situation), effectively turning the entire inheritance over to the remaining sibling (which yes, the inheritance wouldn't do her much good there, but her plans, including her will, involves disbursing her assets to various friends and charitable interests).

So, my central question is, does the death of an inheritor during the probate process result in their "share" reverting to the remaining inheritors? This is a Pennsylvania case, for the sake of state law.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The common law rule was that to inherit you have to outlive the decedent from whom you are inheriting, and that the inheritance would pass to your estate if you died before distribution was made.

Statutes in some jurisdictions provide that someone must survive for a longer period than that to be eligible to inherit, often five days, in order to simplify the factual issues in the common situation of a joint accident. Pennsylvania [is one such state](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/intestate-succession-pennsylvania.html#:%7E:text=Survivorship%20period.,receive%20any%20of%20your%20property.).

But a will or trust can deviate from the default rule, and in U.S. practice, driven by federal estate tax laws, it isn't uncommon to require someone to survive the decedent by at least six months to inherit from them under an instrument.

In this case, where more than a year has passed since the death, the inheritance would not lapse for these reasons.

It also isn't uncommon for a trust, either established during life, or established at death, to provide that distributions from the trust are made at the discretion of the trustee and to require in those cases that the person receiving the distribution also be living at the time of the distribution. These trusts also typically contain specific provisions that spell out the rights of a beneficiary who dies before the trust is fully distributed.

Comment: Ah, both of her parents have deceased. The probate process is just dragging on.

Answer (score 5):

No, at least not in the jurisdictions I know. If she dies now, it's the same as if she had died before the parents: Her share will be distributed as if she had lived, which means it will primarily go to her children and spouse, or to whoever she had given it in her will. If she does not have children (and has not written a will on her own), then, depending on local inheritance laws, the assets may fall back to her siblings, which could then be the group that started the fight.

**Clarification**

Jurisdiction: [switzerland](/questions/tagged/switzerland) (the link to the pensylvania website in the other answer interestingly shows very similar rules)

Let's assume this family tree:

```
Alice -o- Bob
       |
   --- | -------------
   |        |        |
Charlie   David     Me  -o- Eli
                         |
                        Frank
```

Also assume no one has left an explicit will.

Now if the later of the parents (Alice or Bob) dies, and all their children are still alive, they inherit in equal parts. But if I had died before Alice the share that would have gone to me is going to Eli and Frank. Charlie and David get the same amount of our parents' assets, regardless of whether I live at the time of their death or not. (Unless of course, I had neither children nor a spouse)

Comment: It may well depend on the specific terms in the will. Per capita vs per stirpes could mean very different things.

Comment: @JonCuster Certainly. Some parts of the will of the deceased may overwrite this (depending on country), but it doesn't look like the deceased wanted that the OPs friend or her children didn't get anything.

Comment: "*If she dies now, it's the same as if she had died **before** the parents:*" Are you sure that is what you meant to write? as written I think it is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I believe you are labeling this snippet of PMF's answer as incorrect: "if she had died before the parents: Her share will be distributed as if she had lived".  (There's a borderline tautology in the answer, it claims A is the same as B because B is the same as A, where the logic is sound but the premise has problems.)  Would it not be possible to go either way, depending on whether "per stirpes" was designated?

Comment: @Ben Voigt
 Yes, a will can specify any set of contingencies and outcomes that the testator pleases. It could say "I leave $X to B, or to B's descendants if B dies before me." It could say anything. But in the simplest case, if it says "I leave $X to B" and nothing more, then in most US states  B gets nothing if B dies first and B's heirs do not get that bequest, the residuary heir gets it. At least that is my understanding. I could be mistaken, and I think some states have a different default rule.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Is that more clear now? Maybe my english is not good enough to understand your point.

Comment: @PMF (And other readers) be aware that the law on inheritance is _very_ different in civil law jurisdictions (like Switzerland) compared to common law jurisdictions (like most of the US, including Pennsylvania).  In fact, I would go so far as to say that a clear, definitive, answer to the question for Switzerland gives *no* guidance as to how the question would be decided in Pennsylvania.  (Unlike say England, or California)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Roughly, the rules specified in https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/intestate-succession-pennsylvania.html are surprisingly similar. The details will be different, but the relevant rule in Pensylvania states: "A grandchild will receive a share only if that grandchild's parent (your son or daughter) is not alive to receive his or her share." which is basically the same as "Predeceased children are replaced by their own issue in all degrees per stirpes."

Comment: My point is that that is pure coincidence.

Comment: @PMF: Note that those Pennsylvania rules are for "if you die *without* a will" - they do not apply if there is a will involved.

Comment: @psmears Sure, yes. That's the same here. As I read the OP, there's no will (or at least none that would affect that) from the parents who have already died and whose asset distribution is being challenged.

Comment: @PMF: The question refers to a "will document", so there is a will in this case...